# check if e-mail is valid and exists

Tags: dns, email-validation

i want to check if an e-mail address is valid and exist.

I mean not using regex. I need a valitadion by using mx.

for example how to check blablabla[at]gmail.com exists on gmail.com

it would be better using CMD (win)

Answer (score 6):

The only reliable way is send a message to the account and require the recipient to do something (e.g. click a unique link in the email).

Comment: Indeed. The rationale behind Matthew's answer: even a properly formatted email sent to a 'valid' -- not-bouncing -- address is no guarentee that it is really delivered to a mailbox and read by a person.

Depending on the  OP's requirements regarding 'drop-all' or 'catch-all' mail addresses, some kind of notification link is required if you want some evidence that a human person read the mail. But then, even mails delivered to a normal mailbox may stay unread (or not-acted-upon) because of SPAM prevention measures.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at **EmailVerify.NET**, a Microsoft .NET component that can validate email addresses according to the IETF standards (including quoted words and non-ASCII characters) and can be easily integrated in your solutions (even if you are planning to make a console-based one). As you asked, the component allows even to contact a foreign mail exchanger to check if a given email address exists or not and reports back every detail of this transaction.

- EmailVerify.NET's web site: http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component
- Online demo: http://cobisi.com/email-validation/validate-address

Disclaimer: I am the lead developer for this component.

Answer (score -3):

Send an email to target email-id and call it invalid if the email bounces back. That's the only way to test authenticity of an email-id.

Comment: This can prove it is invalid (if it bounces) but not that it is valid (if there is no reply, it can mean it was silently eaten by the MTA).