# How to get valid email id

Tags: email-validation

Hello
i want to know the email id is working or not.

for example if i am writing
mihir@gmail.com

then how could i know that this is valid email id
it means it is already exist on web or not??

i want to do it **without sending email to user**

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if e-mail is valid and exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988282/check-if-e-mail-is-valid-and-exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a confirmation code to validate , when user confirms that means it exist,

Comment: @Mihir: You can't do it without, I am afraid. For spam-prevention reasons I doubt that a server simply allows you to query for existing mailboxes.

Comment: i have found one link which was doing it with cost of 150$ but i was not sure about its accuracy

Comment: @org.live.java: You are still sending mail, and most email clients don't automatically load web-images. I thought about trying to brute-force login into the account using POP3 or IMAP, just to see if the account exists, but this is too silly =)

Comment: @Jens thats true. but its surely a workaround. anyways deleted that from answer

Comment: @org.live.java Thanks that's good idea but isn't there any way to ping valid email id????

Comment: @Mihir, no. there are no other way

Comment: can't we check for known domain like gmail yahoo?

Comment: @Mihir of course _NO_ , no mail service provider wish to exploit their client with spams.

Comment: @Mihir, you can always upvote and mark it as answer if it is the case:)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the domain of the e-mail and make a ping to that address. If the web server response "ok", you know that the domain of e-mail address is valid.

Although you really do not really know if the e-mail is correct without confirmation by the user who writes.

Regards!

Comment: this way i can get is valid domain but can i get a valid user of valid domain?????

Comment: @Mihir: Correct. And thats as far as you can get without trying to send a mail.

Comment: No, that's the problem :( .Maybe you can send an e-mail to this e-mail address and, if you do not receive an error such that "the mailbox does not exist" or something, is that the user account really does exist (though perhaps not in use :) )

Comment: that is domain dependent , and also one should not take decision on such mails.